# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

Im attempting to execute this query

```
def onFlaskPostRequest():
    givenUrl = flask.request.form["url"]
    query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM submittedUrls WHERE original_url=%s")
    queryData = (givenUrl)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, queryData)
    for x in cursor: 
        print(x)
```

When cursor.execute(query, queryData) gets executed I get an error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

Im not too sure why, this seems to follow the format of other queries ive executed. 
Im running on python version 3.8 32bit, mysql-connector-python version 8.0.18 and mysql version 8.0.18

Comment: `queryData` should be a tuple, not a string, you need a comma: `queryData = ("givenUrl",)`

Comment: I think that the problem is the variable url ...may that contain a character special or something like this.....can you print query  before??

Comment: Barmar is right, that fixed it. 

GiovaniSalazar Ive verified that it only returns a string

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar gave the right answer. queryData has to be a tuple so I had to use queryData = (givenUrl,) in order for everything to work